# Getting value attribute of li tag with jquery version 1.7.2 gives '0' when value is string

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I am using jquery version 1.7.2, If i create an li with assigning 'value' attribute with some string. and then when I try to get it with attr or prop method it gives me '0' and when I use native getAttribute method it returns me the string, Why it is happening like this? How can I get string value using jQuery only?

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7jfzs8m/1/) for it.

```
<ul>
<li id='strValue' value="someValue">test</li>
<li id='intValue' value="123">test</li>
</ul>
```

By changing attribute name from value to anyother will work that I know, but I want to know that why with 'value' attribute specifically, it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li` elements do not have a `value` attribute. To store custom information with an element, you should use `data` attributes. Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="strValue" data-value="someValue">test</li>
    <li id="intValue" data-value="123">test</li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('li').click(function () {
    var thisProp = $(this).data('value');
    console.log(thisProp);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o7jfzs8m/3/)

Comment: here we are changing attribute name, my main concern is why can't we use value attribute for this?

Comment: @ParagBhayani because it is not part of the HTML standard for the `li` element. If you use it, the page will be invalid and you may see rendering and JS problems.

Answer (score 1):

`value` is not an attribute of `li` tag. Use `data-value` instead if you want to.

```
<ul>
<li id='strValue' data-value="someValue">test</li>
<li id='intValue' data-value="123">test</li>
</ul>

<script>
alert($('#intValue').attr('data-value'));
alert($('#strValue').attr('data-value'));
</script>
```

Comment: here we are changing attribute name, my main concern is why can't we use value attribute for this?

Comment: Because you can't just go ahead and use any attribute with any other attribute. Everything in DOM has to be registered. You can register your custom attributes on your page with javascript. Only then you'll be technically able to modify them in DOM tree.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use 'value' attribute in the li tag. Also if you use it should only hold numeric value.

Instead of 'value' you can use the 'data-value' attribute and can set its value.

You can then use the .attr() method to get the string.

here is the updated fiddle.

```
$(this).attr('data-value');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o7jfzs8m/1/

Comment: here we are changing attribute name, my main concern is why can't we use value attribute for this?

Comment: You cannot use value attribute as It does not goes through HTML standard. You need to change the attribute. @ParagBhayani